# How random are MATLAB's pseudorandom number generators?

Tags: matlab, random

I read on MATLAB's docs that they use a Mersenne Twister for their rand() and randi() functions.

I wrote some sample code to test randomness:

```
rng('shuffle'); 
rand_arr = zeros(10, 10);
for i=1:10
    rand_arr(i,:) = randi(800, 1, 10);
end

uncollided = 0;
for p=1:10
    if length(rand_arr(:,p)) == length(unique(rand_arr(:,p)))
        uncollided = uncollided + 1;
    end
end

disp(uncollided/10);
```

The number of uncollided sets for a set 10 numbers ended up being 95% sets on average, which seems to be too low. It gets worse as I decrease the universe of randi(). I thought a Mersenne Twister would have better values. Is there a more "random" generator available?

I'm using MATLAB v2017.

Thanks.

Comment: The Marsenne Twister passes a lot of quite serious randomness tests. I would be surprised if you managed to poke a hole in it with such a simple statistics. It is the de facto standard today. But there are better ones, I like the very recent [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org). Not sure anyone made a MATLAB interface yet.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it was just a miscalculation. For those who are curious, the calculation is thus:

800! / (790!*(800<sup>10</sup>)) ~ .945

The question as to which is the best random number generator still stands, though.

Comment: Hmm, I got 0.955. How did you derive your calculation?

Comment: I did (D = total number of possible desirable variations)/(T = total number of possible variations) where D = 10! * (800 choose 10) * 800^790 and T = 800^800.